# How to remove an array item using Play Morphia

Tags: playframework, morphia

I have a structure like the following and am trying to remove one item from the array. I have not been able to figure this out so far. Any suggestions?

```
{
   "_id" : "4fd4466c03644ec6ec6d5fe1",
   "fruit" : [

         { "id" : "4fd4466c03644ec6ec6d5fdf", "name" : "avocado", "quantity" : "2"  },
         { "id" : "4fd4466c03644ec6ec6d5fe0", "name" : "apple",   "quantity" : "34" },

   ]
}
```

I have a model of "cart" that has an embedded document called "fruit". Yes they are bogus examples, but it's simpler to explain a cart of fruit than what I am working on. The furthest I got with the calls.

```
MorphiaQuery q = Cart.q().filter("_id",cartid);
Cart.o().removeAll("fruit", ?????).update(q);
```

Any guidance would be awesome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out the Cart from which you want to remove one fruit:

```
Cart cart = Cart.findById(cartid);
```

Second locate the fruit and remove it:

```
for (Fruit f: cart.fruit) {
    if (f.name.equals("apple")) {
        cart.fruit.remove(f);
        cart.save();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to be more efficient using the $pull operand?

Comment: I have seen the following syntax in mongodb but wasn't sure how morphia would do this.{ $pull: { posts: { id: "wwwwwiasdfn234oiasf" } } }

Comment: hmm... You are right, can you try `Cart.o().removeAll("fruit.name", "apple").update(Cart.q().filter("_id", theId));`